# How to make a drop down menu and connect the choice to a CBGV

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django and am struggling to understand how to make a user accessible connection between two models.

models.py:

```
class StudyGroup(models.Model):
  start_date = models.DateTimeField()
  end_date = models.DateTimeField()
  ex_1_trial = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
  ex_2_trial = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
  ...
  def __str__(self):
    return self.studygroup_name

class Patient(models.Model):
  type = models.CharField('Type', max_length=20, db_index=True, help_text='s', primary_key=True)
  patient_name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=200, db_index=True, help_text='n')
  studygroup = models.ForeignKey(StudyGroup, verbose_name='StudyGroup')
  ...
  def __str__(self):
    return self.patient_name
```

views.py:

```
class SidebarList(object):
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SidebarList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['my_patient_list'] = Patient.objects.order_by('company_name')
    return context

class PatientStatsView(SidebarList, DetailView):
  model = Patient
  template_name = 'screener/patient_stats.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CompanyStatsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ... some sorting and stuff here ...
    context['blah'] = some_values
    return context
```

Now I want to make a drop down menu with the list of available studygroups in it and allow the user to select one to associate with a particular patient in the template associated with PatientStatsView. If a studygroup is already associated with a the patient instance, then that studygroup needs to be selected by default in the drop down.

I am unclear about the best ways to achieve this and to have the selection verified and saved in the patient model.

Is this best done in the form.py?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I see it can be done is via the `forms.py`, indeeed. Especially, that you will be altering the data in your database. You would want to use `POST` method together with `CSRF`, because of that.

So you first of all you need to create `forms.py` with a 
[`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)(I find it most suitable for your task), which

> Allows the selection of a single model object, suitable for representing a foreign key.

and set [`queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset) parameter on it.

> A **QuerySet** of model objects from which the choices for the field will be derived, and which will be used to validate the user’s selection.

You could do it for example like this:

```
# forms.py
...
class PatientForm(forms.Form):
    studygroups = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StudyGroup.objects.all(),
                                         label='Study groups')
    ...
```

Then you would check in your view if the page was requested via `POST` or `GET` method. If user views the form for the first time - via `GET` method, then you would want to set the default value of user's `StudyGroup` if user is assigned to one, else return `None`. For example:

### CBV:

```
class HomeView(View):
    form_class = PatientForm
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = {'studygroups': request.user.patient.studygroup.pk}
        form = self.form_class(initial=initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

### CBGV:

```
class HomeView(FormView):
    form_class = PatientForm
    template_name = 'home.html'
    success_url = '/success/'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(HomeView, self).get_initial()
        initial['studygroups'] = self.request.user.patient.studygroup.pk
        return initial

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(HomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

### FBV:

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PatientForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
        form.save()
else:
    # some logic which would assign the patient studygroup's pk 
    # to default_group_pk variable.
    # or None if no default group should be selected
    # i.e. user is not logged in or is not assigned to any studygroup.
    # You could get logged in Patient's studygroup via:
    # default_group_pk = request.user.patient.studygroup.pk
    form = PatientForm(initial={'studygroups': default_group_pk})
...
```

Then simply render the form in your html:

```
<form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Given that I'm trying to use CBV's (for the inheritance of SideBarList, etc.), should I override the form_valid(), get() and post() methods to implement the code you propose? I'm not crystal clear on how to do that, but there appears to be some logic in that course.

Comment: Great. I think I'm beginning to see the connections. Still, I don't understand why to use the form.is_valid() method instead of overriding the form_valid() method. Is this a "best practices" question or do these methods function differently in a way that my proposed technique won't work?

Comment: @PhotonWrangler I updated code with CBGV where you use form_valid() method. There are really many ways you could do that. Which one you choose is up to you. There is nice [article](http://programeveryday.com/post/writing-django-views-function-based-views-class-based-views-and-class-based-generic-views/) where you can read more.